# ng-click with ng-checked not updating checkbox state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

small question (possible a logic err), I am trying to get the checkbox to update itself automatically after clicking it and in the same time using the rest api to PUT the changes in DB, and the PUT mothod works, it updates the DB but it`s not updating the checkbox state itself only if I refresh the page, the checkbox will update.

And I have this simple code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="action.state" ng-click="setState($event, key, action)"><div class="track"><div class="handle"></div></div>
```

and back-end as this:

```
.controller('Actions', function ($scope, $filter, $resource, $ionicActionSheet, $ionicModal) {
    var actionListResource = $resource('/api/actions/');

    actionListResource.query(function (data) {
        $scope.actions = data;
    });

    $scope.setState = function (event, index, action) {

        if (action.widget === 'toggle' && action.state === 1) {
            action.state = 0;
        }
        else {
            action.state = 1;
        }

        event.preventDefault();

        var actionsResource = $resource('/api/actions/:actionId/', {actionId:'@id'}, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        }); 
    };
    ...more code here
})
```

`action.state` is always a 1 or 0 value, I've checked the `$scope.actions[index].state` and it`s updating itself when I click the checkbox.

Thank you!

Comment: use ng-model instead of ng-checked to update the checkbox.

Comment: i`ve tried it, doesn't work, the checkbox is not updated, when I click it, the event is triggered but, no movement on checkbox in front-end

Comment: add plkr or fiddle.

Comment: We have used event.preventDefault() in our code. It might be due to that. What's the purpose of event.preventDefault() in this code?

Comment: event.preventDefault()   - this was it! my god...i`ve mist it every time...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="action" ng-click="setState()">
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.setState = function() {
      window.alert($scope.action);
      // $scope.action value will be true or false
    };
  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI, this doesn't help at all, in fact, I want something totally different.
My problem is not how to use this concept, is that the checkbox doesnt go checked or unchecked when I click on it and setState changes the state of it and updates the DB.

Comment: Please see this example https://jsfiddle.net/KarthikParameswaran/a6jq1mk7/, checkbox works fine for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try ng-model instead of ng-checked. The toggle stuff looks unecessary. ng-change could also be used to trigger the request.
In their docs they solve exactly the problem you describe.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: It'd be helpful if you explained the merits of `ng-model` instead of just stating that the OP should use it. *Why* should he do so and *how*.

Comment: thank you seems legit, but i`ve also tried and I got a huge angular err, I will try it today again, I will update, thank you.

Comment: There was a event.preventDefault() - this was it!
Don`t know how i`ve mist it!